# Cannot select element by XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

global:

```
import re

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from patterns import PATTERNS


PATTERNS = {

    'select_list': {
        'click': r'javascript.*[0-9]+.*\s.*[0-9]+.*\s.*{}.*;',
        'select_list_views': r'/Integration/chooselist/{}'
    },

    login: {"..."}

}

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(r"login_uri")
```

This section directs to targeted page,

```
views(PATTERNS['login'])  # func performs login

list_name = r'ABC TEXT.COM'
pk = 1234

# get lists_views
lists_href = r'//a[@href="{}"]'.format(PATTERNS['select_list']['select_list_views'].format(pk))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, lists_href))).click()

source = driver.page_source  # page source HTML
```

then `element_href` is to be parsed from: `source = driver.page_source`,
using flag `list_name`

`element_href = '//a[@href="{}".format(re.findall(r'javascript.*[0-9]+.*\s.*[0-9]+.*\s.*{}.*;'.format(list_name), source)[0])`

will relove to :

```
'//a[@href="javascript:postSelect(&quot;123&quot;, &quot;1234&quot;, &quot;ABC TEXT.COM&quot;);"]'
```

which is slightly different than inspected one,
seems that a JS function reformats the link, i don't know when exactly.

element's link from inspection:

```
<a href="javascript:postSelect("123", "1234", "ABC TEXT.com");">Select</a>
```

finally when i try to select element by XPATH:

```
try:
    element_href = r'//a[@href="{}"]'.format(re.findall(PATTERNS['select_list']['click'].format(list_name), source)[0])

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, element_href))).click()

except IndexError:
    print("could not parse link")
```

i was able to click the element by selecting it with XPATH copied from Firefox:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[104]/td[3]/a').click()
```

The only problem with copied XPATH, there is no dynamic way to map it to `list_name` since `104 != 123`

scripts in html_source:

```
    <div style="float: none; clear: both;"></div>

    </div>




<script data-cfasync="false" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js"></script><script src="https://some_url/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://some_url/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://some_url/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://some_url/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <script src="https://some_url/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
    <script src="https://some_url/flatui-checkbox.js"></script>
    <script src="https://some_url/flatui-radio.js"></script>
    <script src="https://some_url/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>
    <script src="https://some_url/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>

    <script src="https://some_url/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowLoadingAJAX() {
            $('body').addClass("loading");
        }

        function HideLoadingAJAX() {
            $('body').removeClass("loading");
        }

        function DisplaySuccessMessage(msg) {
            $('#alert_danger').hide();
            $('#alert_info').hide();

            $('#alert_success_message').html(msg);
            $('#alert_success').show();
        }

        function AppendSuccessMessage(msg) {
            $('#alert_danger').hide();
            $('#alert_info').hide();

            $('#alert_success_message').html($('#alert_success_message').html() + '<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&rarr;&nbsp;' + msg);
            $('#alert_success').show();
        }

        function DisplayErrorMessage(msg) {
            $('#alert_success').hide();
            $('#alert_info').hide();

            $('#alert_danger_message').html(msg);
            $('#alert_danger').show();
        }

        function DisplayInfoMessage(msg) {
            $('#alert_danger').hide();
            $('#alert_success').hide();

            $('#alert_info_message').html(msg);
            $('#alert_info').show();
        }

        function HideSuccessMessage() {
            $('#alert_success_message').html('');
            $('#alert_success').hide();
        }

        function HideErrorMessage() {
            $('#alert_danger_message').html('');
            $('#alert_danger').hide();
        }

        function HideInfoMessage() {
            $('#alert_info_message').html('');
            $('#alert_info').hide();
        }


        function loginAsSuperUser(id) {
            $('#SuperLoginAsUserID').val(id);
            $('#superLoginForm').submit();
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#some_string_body').css('display', 'block');

            var tooltipOptions = { placement: 'right' };
            $('.some_string_tooltip').tooltip(tooltipOptions);

            var popoverOptions = { placement: 'right' };
            $('.some_string_popover').popover(popoverOptions);

            $('#alert_success_close_button').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#alert_success_message').html('');
                $('#alert_success').hide();
            });

            $('#alert_danger_close_button').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#alert_danger_message').html('');
                $('#alert_danger').hide();
            });

            $('#alert_info_close_button').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#alert_info_message').html('');
                $('#alert_info').hide();
            });


        });
    </script>

    <script>
        var href_parts = window.location.href.split('/');
        var lastFancyboxHeight = 0;
        var fancyDocReady = false;
        var fancyRefreshParent = false;

        function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
            return unsafe
                .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
                .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
                .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
                .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
                .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
        }

        function getFancyboxY(id) {
            var bs = $('#' + id + '-box-statement');
            if (bs.length && bs.offset() && bs.offset().top) {
                return (bs.offset().top + 'px');
            } else {
                return '200px';
            }
        }

        function showActivityLog() {
            var href_iframe_url = href_parts[0] + '//' + href_parts[2] + '/Activity/Recent';

            //$('#fancy-styler').html('.fancy-styler-top { top: ' + getFancyboxY(id) + ' !important; }');

            $.fancybox({
                type: 'iframe',
                href: href_iframe_url,
                scrolling: 'no',
                padding: 0,
                openEffect: 'none',
                closeEffect: 'none',
                closeClick: false,
                nextClick: false,
                autoResize: false,
                autoHeight: false,
                autoSize: false,
                autoCenter: true,
                fitToView: false,
                //fixed: false,
                width: 1160,
                height: 900,
                tpl: {
                    closeBtn: '<div style="position: absolute; top: -22px; left: 0px; z-index: 8040; height: 28px; line-height: 30px; background-color: #428bca; color: #fff; cursor: pointer; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 12px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-top-left-radius: 6px;">Recent Activity</div>'
                },
                afterClose: function () {

                },
                beforeShow: function () {
                    //$(".fancybox-wrap").addClass("fancy-condition-editor-2");
                    $(".fancybox-wrap").addClass("fancy-styler-top-2");
                }
            });
        }

        function getActivitiesColorAjax() {
            NumProfileActivityChecks++;

            if ($('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').length) {
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
                var dataPost = {
                    __RequestVerificationToken: $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val(),
                    p1: "a",
                    p2: "b"
                };
                $.post("/Activity/PostColorAjax", dataPost, function (data) {
                    if (!data.color || data.color === 'green') {
                        //$('#profile-name-icon').css('color', '#1abc9c');
                        $('#profile-name-icon').css('color', OriginalProfileNameIconColor);
                    } else {
                        $('#profile-name-icon').css('color', '#e74c3c');
                    }

                    //console.log('PostColorAjax (' + NumProfileActivityChecks + '): ' + data.color);

                    if (NumProfileActivityChecks <= 10) {
                        //for the first 10 minutes, check every 60 seconds.
                        setTimeout(getActivitiesColorAjax, 60000);
                    } else if (NumProfileActivityChecks <= 120) {
                        //for the first 120 minutes, check every 120 seconds.
                        setTimeout(getActivitiesColorAjax, 120000);
                    } else {
                        //after 120 minutes, start checking with exponential backoff.
                        //120 + (NumProfileActivityChecks - 120) * 2
                        var tot = 1000 * (120 + Math.pow((NumProfileActivityChecks - 120), 2));
                        setTimeout(getActivitiesColorAjax, tot);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(
            function () {
                //$('a[rel="popover"]').popover({placement: 'bottom'});
                //$('#settings_general_mc_api_key_error').addClass('alert-error error');
            }
        );

        function postSelect(id, connectionID, ListName)
        {
            $("#ID").val(id.toString());
            $("#IntegrationID").val(connectionID);
            $("#ListName").val(ListName);
            $("#emChooseListForm").submit();
        }

    </script>




</body>
</html>
```

Although link is matched from the page source code directly,
driver can't locate element and simply timesout..

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, element_href))).click()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-53-7a3495af695d>", line 1, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, element_href))).click()

  File "c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException
```

Please tolerate my description if it is poor, this is my first post on stackoverflow,
Thanks

Comment: You need to provide your URL or your full page source so we can have a look.

Comment: thank you for responding, i will try to share more of the HTML
the only reason i couldn't share the source is that it has private data,
my access to this site is private also.

Comment: I am totally new to JS, so im not sure but i think to be able to target this element, is there some sort of JS that i need to invoke?

Comment: I mean full page source is all your HTML code of your current web page. The problem is that I want to check if there is your wanted element in that page. If it isn't, there are 2 cases: 1. You have to wait for that element. 2. Your element is under an iframe.

Comment: there is only one unique link parsed by `list_name` from source code and it does exist in code and i was able to match it:
`'//a[@href="javascript:postSelect(&quot;123&quot;, &quot;1234&quot;, &quot;ABC TEXT.COM&quot;);"]'`

because `list_name` is a unique identifier for selection elements

Comment: If you can find the element with full XPath copied from dev tool, but you can't find it with your XPath, you can check your XPath within your browser. An easy way, open your web on Chrome, open Dev tool (F12), press `Ctrl+F` to find and fill it with your XPath, it will show you the result. Harder way with FireFox, open Dev tools, switch to `Console` tab, type `$x("/your/xpath")` then press enter (this is called "jquery find by xpath").

Comment: finally, this is the solution in my case,

select element using css_selector:
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='{}']".format(list_name))`

or

`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='{}']".format(list_name))))`